# Why need HashMap to relocate elements while rehashing?

Tags: java, hashmap

When hashmap reaches allowed size (capacity*loadFactor) then it automatically increased and after that all elements will be relocated into the new indexies. So, why need to perform this relocation?

Comment: The whole reason HashMap has expected O(1) access is that there is an expected O(1) elements per bucket.  If you didn't resize the map you'd end up with O(n) elements per bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rehashing` is required because the calculation used when mapping a `key` value to a bucket is dependent on the total number of buckets. When the number of buckets changes (to increase capacity), the new mapping calculation may map a given `key` to a different bucket.

In other words, lookups for some or all of the previous entries may fail to behave properly because the entries are in the wrong buckets after growing the backing store.

While this may seem unfortunate, you actually want the mapping function to take into account the total number of buckets that are available. In this way, all buckets can be utilized and no entries get mapped to buckets that do not exist.

There are other data structures that do not have this property, but this is the standard way that hash maps work.

Answer (score 2):

Because it makes hash table sparse, allowing elements to sit in their own buckets instead of piling up in small number of buckets.

When several elements hit the same bucket, `HashMap` has to create a list (and sometimes even a tree) which is bad for both memory footprint and performance of elements retrieval. So, to prevent the number of such collisions, `HashMap` is growing its internal hash table and rehashes.